# Logical Equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have to show that :

```
((p => q) v (~(p ^ ~q) ^ T)) ≡ ~p v q
```

I've gotten this far :

```
((p => q) v (~(p ^ ~q) ^ T)) ≡ ~p v q 
((p => q) v ((~p ^ q) ^ T)) ≡ ~p v q          by DeMorgan & Double Negation
((~p v q) v ((~p ^ q) ^ T)) ≡ ~p v q               by Conditional
```

I'm stuck on the last line. Am I going down the right pathway so far?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, when applying De Morgans Law, you did not change the "and" to "or". Also, it is useful to note that $r\wedge T\equiv r$ and $r\vee r\equiv r$.

Comment: Ahhh! Nice catch

Comment: Wait, (~p ^ q) can become just 'r' in a sense?

Comment: @Jack   Is really $r \wedge T \equiv r$ ?

Comment: Mmm by Identity I could see that happening. But I'm just wondering if you can apply that to (~p ^ q)

Comment: Take $r$ to be $\neg (p\wedge \neg q)$ and see what you get.

Comment: $p\implies q$ is synonymous with $(\sim p)\vee q$. So  for the expression $\sim (p\wedge \sim q)$ in the first line, we have $\sim(p\wedge \sim q) \iff ((\sim p)\vee  (\sim \sim q))\iff ((\sim p)\vee q)\iff (p\implies q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By DeMorgan & Double Negation
\begin{align}
((p \implies q) \lor (\neg(p \land \neg q) \land T))&\equiv((p \implies q) \lor ((\neg p \lor q) \land T))
\\
&\equiv((\neg p \lor q) \lor ((\neg p \lor q) \land T))\quad\text{by }p\land T \equiv p
\\
&\equiv(\neg p \lor q) \lor (\neg p \lor q)\quad\text{by idempotent law}
\\
&\equiv(\neg p \lor q)
\\
\end{align}

Comment: What logical equivalence was used for the 2nd to last line?

Comment: @Xirol - $p \land T \equiv p$ is called sometimes *Identity law*; see [Table of Logical Equivalences](http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf).